# How do you add references to dlls in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, itext

I used nuget to succesfully install iTextSharp XMLWorker extension in my project.

However, I cannot use it without also "adding a reference" to the iTextSharp XML Worker dll.

Currently, in the solution explorer for my project file, I am right clicking on "References" and choosing to Add Reference.  From the list of available assemblies, I cannot locate anything called iTextSharp or XML Worker.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9):

Just for the sake of new visitors who might be having the same problem, the `Package Manager Console` serves the purpose. 
Go to `Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Package Manager Console`.
For iTextSharp Library, run the command.

> Install-Package iTextSharp

For XML Worker, run

> Install-Package iTextSharp.xmlworker

On success, `Build` your project and you should be able to find the references.

Answer (score 2):

You do have to search for it .

My usual method is :

1) Right-click on the project, select Add -> New folder (I name it "lib" )

2) From your file explorer, drag the file to this folder to create a copy

3) Right-click on references, Select "Browse...", go to your source folder, you'll see your "lib" folder freshly created, and you'll be able to select as many files as you want, and then check them, and it's ok
They won't appear "by themselves" in the list, you must browse your filesystem for them (at least as far as I know with my limited knowledge of VS2013)

The first steps are optional but for the sake of good organisation I think it's important to keep a copy of your useful dlls with your source files. Useful for source control as well.

Comment: That was the only working solution on my old web form from 2007 (back in the days, when nuget didn't exist)

Answer (score 1):

What I did is I right-click the project file in the right side and click the `Reference` then from that i click the `browse` then find the path for my `.dll`